# memory handling capacity of 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

What is the maximum amount of ddr that can be installed in a 64 bit ubuntu linux system computer?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ubuntu help wiki, the maximum amount of memory being addressed via Ubuntu is roughly 1TB

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#Memory

Comment: ...so you'll almost certainly be limited by the capacity of your motherboard.

Comment: Thanks for your help folks, much appreciated. I am about to try linux for the first time.